# Find all functions $f \in C^4(\mathbb R)$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb R, f(x) \leq 0$ and $f^{(4)}(x) \geq 0$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I can solve this problem if I assume $f(x)$ is a polynomial function. But for the general case of $f(x)$, I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: Usually, the blackboard bold $\mathbb C$ refers to the complex numbers... so you might prefer to write just $C^4(\mathbb R)$ if you mean (as I eventually came to suspect) fourt-times-continuously-differentiable functions on $\mathbb R$...

Comment: What kind of characterization of these functions would you like?  For any choice of $f^{(4)}(x)$ that is a nice non-negative function with a finite integral, you'll find an infinite family of solutions.

Comment: @Paul Garrett: You are correct. Thanks for correcting my mistake.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: The problem asks for all functions, so I wonder if there is a way to characterize the set of all solutions in a mathematically rigorous way?

Comment: The question probably gives the most efficient and informative characterization of this set.